# Exercise 6.2.4 of "Fundamentals of the Theory of Groups".

Tags: group-theory, wreath-product

Let $A$ and $B$ groups and $A\wr B$ is a restricted wreath product. Prove that
$$
[A\wr B, A\wr B]=[B, B]\ H
$$
where $\mathrm{fun}(B, A)=\{f| f:B\longrightarrow A\quad \mathrm{supp}f<+\infty\}$ and
$H=\left\{f|f\in\mathrm{fun}(B, A)\ \prod_{b\in B}f(b)\equiv e\pmod{[A,A]}\right\}$
($A\wr B=B\ \mathrm{fun}(B, A)$ and $bf\cdot b'f'=bb'\ f^{b'}f'$).

This task is from the book [Fundamentals of the Theory of Groups](https://link.springer.com/book/9781461299660).

I did the following:
$$
[A\wr B, A\wr B]=[B\ \mathrm{fun}(B, A), B\ \mathrm{fun}(B, A)]= [B, B]\ H
$$
and began to consider the binary operation $[xf,\ yg]=[x,\ y]h$ and tried to prove that it was true $\prod_{b\in B}h(b)\equiv e\pmod{[A,A]}$. But I could not.

Please give me a hint on how to solve this problem

Comment: Please use subject lines that are informative about the mathematical content of your question.

Comment: Which exercise is it in particular? (Where is it in the book?)

Comment: Task number is 6.2.4

Comment: `\pmod{[A,A]}` will produce the parentheses, roman typeface "mod", and provide correct spacing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll definitely take it into account next time.

Comment: The RHS of your equality is missing the term $[B,{\rm fun}(B,A)]$. You should split the problem into its two associated containments.